# get file metadata from S3 using Python boto

Tags: python, boto

I have some binary files in `AWS S3`, i need to get the `file metadata` like `created time`, `modified time` and accessed time using Python Boto API?

What we tried was copy the files to EC2 instance, from there we used `os` module `stat` method to get the times. I hope when we copy the files to EC2 instance these details are changed.

Sample code what i tried:

```
stat = os.stat(inputFile)
createdTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(stat[9]).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")
```

How to directly get these details from S3?

Answer (score 21):

Boto3 has a function [S3.Client.head_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object):

> The HEAD operation retrieves metadata from an object without returning
> the object itself. This operation is useful if you're only interested
> in an object's metadata.

Sample code to step through files in a bucket and request metadata:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import boto3
s3client = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = s3client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket='MyBucketName')
for bucket in page_iterator:
    for file in bucket['Contents']:
        print(file['Key'])
        try:
            metadata = s3client.head_object(Bucket='MyBucketName', Key=file['Key'])
            print(metadata)
        except:
            print("Failed {}".format(file['Key']))
```

Answer (score 1):

use boto3 instead of boto.
you can look at https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html for anything about boto3's s3 apis. there are not many filters available, check if what you need is available there. Check this to start with https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2