# S3 - Lambda python - check file encoding

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

we have huge files in s3 bucket and we are trying to implement lambda (python) and check files encoding. For sure we dont want to load these files on efs connected to lambda to be able to open it. So some metadata streams I think could be suitable but I am not able to find any proper solution.

Maybe anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get file metadata from S3 using Python boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271946/get-file-metadata-from-s3-using-python-boto)

Comment: @baduker this doesnt return ContentEncoding value for some reason.